# I'm trying to create a monster that spreads in every direction infinitely but for some reason it's just making a "+" symbol

Tags: 2d, godot, gdscript

**Monster script** (it is connected to 2DSprite in Monster.tscn)

```
extends Sprite2D

var monster = preload("res://Monster.tscn")

func _process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_accept"):
        var random_right = randi() % 10 + 1
        var random_left = randi() % 10 + 1
        var random_up = randi() % 10 + 1
        var random_down = randi() % 10 + 1
        
        if random_right <= 5:
            var instance = monster.instantiate()
            get_parent().add_child(instance)
            
            instance.position.x = position.x + 80
            instance.position.y = position.y
            
        if random_left <= 5:
            var instance = monster.instantiate()
            get_parent().add_child(instance)
            
            instance.position.x = position.x - 80
            instance.position.y = position.y
            
        if random_up <= 5:
            var instance = monster.instantiate()
            get_parent().add_child(instance)
            
            instance.position.x = position.x
            instance.position.y = position.y + 80
            
        if random_down <= 5:
            var instance = monster.instantiate()
            add_child(instance)
            
            instance.position.x = position.x
            instance.position.y = position.y - 80
```

**How it works**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/upgc3.png)

I checked if everything is connected how it should be. My only guess to why it is not working properly is because it takes position.x and position.y from the starting monster and I don't know how to change that so please help.

Comment: Does the root of Monster.tscn have this script attached? If they don't, then they do not spread. - You have an error: In the last statement you are using `add_child`, it should be like the others. - Suggestion: `randf() < 0.5` is a fair coinflip. - Note: Nothing is preventing multiple of these instances to be in the same position.